# Invalid token in class struct interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a situation on visual studio 2015  .. i have the next code  :

```
Private Sub TBwe.Text 
Changed;(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.System.EventArgs) Handles TBWe.TextChanged

    if    Strings.Len(TBWe.Text) = 6 then
        TBEt.Focus();
    End Sub
```

i have invalid token in class , struct , or interface

Can any body help me  ?

Comment: VB does *not* use `;` as statement terminator (C# does). Try removing them.

Comment: thank you ..problem rezolved

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  Private Sub TBwe_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TBWe.TextChanged

    If Strings.Len(TBWe.Text) = 6 Then
        TBEt.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```